# adding all person in form of array in ABRecordRef

Tags: iphone

how can i add the people from the contacts to 'people'- array then to abrecordref.??? Actually i want all the contacts in tableview and can able to edit individual record. here is my code:

```
-(void)showPersonViewController
{      
    // Fetch the address book 
        ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
        // Search for the person named "rubal" in the address book
        NSArray *people = (NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyPeopleWithName(addressBook, CFSTR("naina"));
        // Display "KETAN" information if found in the address book 
        if ((people != nil) && [people count])
        {
            ABRecordRef person = (ABRecordRef)[people objectAtIndex:0];
            ABPersonViewController *picker = [[[ABPersonViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
            picker.personViewDelegate = self;
            picker.displayedPerson = person;
            // Allow users to edit the person’s information

            picker.allowsEditing = YES;
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:picker animated:YES];
        }
        else 
        {
            // Show an alert if "KETAN" is not in Contacts
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" 
                                                      message:@"Could not find naina in the Contacts application" 
                                                      delegate:nil 
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
         }
           [people release];
           CFRelease(addressBook);
}
```

instead of only 'naina' i want all record in table view and edit individually

Answer (score 0):

Look at ABPerson Class Reference. There is a list of other copy functions, including the one you seek, `ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(ABAddressBookRef ab)`

Answer (score 0):

comment out your function and add this one and see if it works

```
-(BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:
(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {


            [peoplePicker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];

            ABPersonViewController *picker = [[ABPersonViewController alloc] init];
            picker.personViewDelegate = self;
            picker.displayedPerson = person;

// Allow users to edit the person’s information
            picker.allowsEditing = YES;
            [picker setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"allowsDeletion"];



            [self.navigationController pushViewController:picker animated:YES];

    return YES;
}
```